# .htaccess Redirect Directive file to directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm writing a .htaccess to support a couple moved files on a site. The concept is that `/filename.htm` is now at `/filename/index.htm` and I want links to it to read just `/filename/`. Here is what I have:

```
redirect permanent /filename.htm http://www.example.com/filename/
```

Will this work as expected? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code looks good, should do the trick.